# How can I capture a screenshot on Windows from an Angle OpenGL ES 2.x application?

Tags: c++, hook, opengl-es-2.0, screenshot

I'm using Angle OpenGL ES 2.x on Windows 7/10 to produce an application that opens a window to draw animations to the screen. From another application (my screenshot recorder) I obtain the process ID of the Angle application, install a Windows hook that employs DLL injection, and force the Angle application to load my custom DLL, which waits for a command from my screenshot recorder to take a screenshot. When that command is received, my DLL is executed, and the screenshot pixel data is returned to my screenshot recorder via a Windows message. This all works perfectly when the OpenGL ES 2.x emulator is PowerVR. However, when using Angle to build the target application (the one that displays the animations and that I wish to screenshot) I only get blank, medium grey screenshots. Here is a snippet of the DLL code which attempts to take the screenshot:

```
......
......

if (message_info->message == WM_TAKESCREENSHOT)
{
    // We will respond to the window specified in the wParam.
    HWND respond_to = HWND(message_info->wParam);

    RECT client_rect;
    GetClientRect(message_info->hwnd, &client_rect);
    int width = client_rect.right - client_rect.left;
    int height = client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top;

    // 4 bytes for width, 4 bytes for height
    //int padded_row_size = _getPaddedRowSize(width, 3); // Account for the stride -> this works for PowerVR and RGB
    int padded_row_size = _getPaddedRowSize(width, 4); // Account for the stride -> this works for Angle and RGBA

    BYTE* response_message = new BYTE[4 + 4 + padded_row_size * height];
    *reinterpret_cast<int*>(response_message) = width;
    *reinterpret_cast<int*>(response_message + 4) = height;

    BYTE* pixels = response_message + 8;

    // The following statement has been found experimentally, and is needed to
    // take screenshots from back-buffered OpenGL ES apps (like the Windows
    // OpenGL ES target built with the PowerVR libs).

    // This configuration works for PowerVR executables, but not for Angle
    //glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);

    // This configuration works for PowerVR executables, but not for Angle
    //glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    // This configuration works for Angle???
    // This code will be executed only when the executable has been pushed to a deterministic animation state
    // by the application C-code. The executable will remain in that frozen state until the screenshot capture is completed
    // and the bind back to the original framebuffer has completed.

    // For Angle
    GLuint framebufferName;
    GLenum err;
    FILE *fp;
    char errs[30];

    // For Angle
    // Get the name of the currently bound framebuffer

    glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, (GLint *)&framebufferName);

    err = glGetError();
    if (GL_NO_ERROR != err)
    {
        fopen_s(&fp, "F:\\errors.log", "a");
        sprintf(errs, "GLGetBind->%d\n", err);
        fprintf(fp, "%s", errs);
        fflush(fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    // For Angle
    // Bind to the final render framebuffer - 0 = the screen
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    err = glGetError();
    if (GL_NO_ERROR != err)
    {
        fopen_s(&fp, "F:\\errors.log", "a");
        sprintf(errs, "GLBind->%d\n", err);
        fprintf(fp, "%s", errs);
        fflush(fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    // For Angle
    // Read the pixels
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    // For Angle debugging

    err = glGetError();
    if (GL_NO_ERROR != err)
    {
        fopen_s(&fp, "F:\\errors.log", "a");
        sprintf(errs, "GLrpxl->%d\n", err);
        fprintf(fp, "%s", errs);
        fflush(fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    // For Angle
    // Bind back to the original framebuffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferName);

    err = glGetError();
    if (GL_NO_ERROR != err)
    {
        fopen_s(&fp, "F:\\errors.log", "a");
        sprintf(errs, "GLreBind->%d\n", err);
        fprintf(fp, "%s", errs);
        fflush(fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }


    COPYDATASTRUCT data_to_send;
    data_to_send.dwData = 0;
    data_to_send.cbData = 4 + 4 + padded_row_size * height;
    data_to_send.lpData = LPVOID(response_message);

    SendMessage(respond_to, WM_COPYDATA, WPARAM(message_info->hwnd), reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(static_cast<LPVOID>(&data_to_send)));
    GetLastError();
    GetCurrentThreadId();
    GetCurrentThreadId();

    delete[] response_message;
}

return ::CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Almost no matter what OpenGL call I make, glGetError() returns a 1282 error code, Invalid Operation. In fact, at the very start of my DLL, if I place a glGetError() there, I will get error 1282, before I have done anything in my DLL. However, I can do a call like glIsFramebuffer() to find which framebuffers are currently bound, and that call gives me a valid return value. I have tried looping the glGetError() until it returns GL_NO_ERROR, but the loop will run forever.

I have tried to bind framebuffer 0 (the screen) and do a glReadPixels() in order to get a screenshot, and I have also tried framebuffer 1, which shows as the only bound framebuffer, but the result is always the same - a 'blank' screenshot with medium-grey pixels.

(Please pardon the ugly error logging instrumentation code - that aided in the debugging of the DLL.)

Why am I not able to bind to a framebuffer that has the contents of the screen and capture the pixel data?

Comment: Are you sure that the [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is current when the code is executed? Is the code executed in a different thread (see [OpenGL and multithreading](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading))?

Comment: As I understand DLL injection via Windows hooks, the DLL that is injected into the target application's program space executes within that space, in the same thread as the target application. If true, then it's all happening in the same thread and that DLL should be able to see the OpenGL context. This works perfectly with PowerVR OpenGL, but not with Angle OpenGL. This morning I will literally parse and examine the pixel data block after my call to glReadPixels() to make sure it isn't a case of getting pixels just fine, but messing up the handling of those pixels when I'm saving them as a PNG

Comment: I just just confirmed that glReadPixels() is not disturbing my local pixel data block in the slightest. I set that block to a known state (all black - all bytes zeroed) before the call, and no bytes were changed by the call. So, as I feared, glReadPixels() fails to return anything. Question - is it normal to destroy the OpenGL context after each rendering to the screen? If that's being done, it might explain why I'm failing to get a screenshot and why nearly every OpenGL call returns the error 1282, Invalid Operation.

Comment: No, its not destroyed, but it is not current. `wglMakeCurrent`

Comment: Not being an OpenGL programmer, can you help me understand whether it might be possible to ask the developer of the target application to keep the context current after each rendering to the screen? Would that be possible, practical? Sorry - I missed your reference to wglMakeCurrent - let me see if Angle has such a call.

Comment: @Rabbid76: I'm pretty sure you nailed it! I've obtained the source code for the target application and the OpenGL context is no longer current once a frame is rendered to the screen (framebuffer 0). I'll wrap my DLL around the swap_buffers() operation to position the screenshot acquisition just before the context goes non-current. Thanks! I'll let you know the outcome.

Comment: Despite a lot of effort, I am still not able to see a valid OpenGL context from within the DLL I have injected into the target application's program space. Instead, I'd like to try to capture the screenshot into a pixel data block in the target application and then, from within my injected DLL, read that block and process it into a PNG on disk as before. To do this I have to share a global variable (data block start addr) with the DLL, and these two pgms (target and DLL) are never linked together by the linker. Can I do that w/o getting link err on the DLL side? No libs are shared btw them.